# Declare Global Variable In OOP PHP

Tags: errors, globals, screen-options

I'm working on my Plugin & i wanted to declare one of the global wordpress variables which is `$current_screen` To Check whether The user is on the target page or some other page, my Approach was like this , but it didn't work out .

```
class my_Class {

    public $current_screen;

    public function __construct() {
        global $current_screen;
        add_action( 'current_screen', array( $this, 'Current_Screen') );
    }

    public function Current_Screen() {
         if ( $current_screen->parent_base == 'slug-page' ) {
             // Do Something ...
         }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Nothing Happens but Fatal Error . So Please Guys I Wanna  Help . Thanks In Advance .

Answer (score 6):

The `$current_screen` is passed as a variable to callables hooked from the `current_screen` hook.

Before this hook, the `$current_screen` isn't set up, so globalizing the variable won't do anything anyway.

Also, WordPress offers the convenience function `get_current_screen()` that returns the global `$current_screen` variable if it exists.

```
class wpse {
  protected $current_screen;
  public function load() {
    add_action( 'current_screen', [ $this, 'current_screen' ] );
  }
  public function current_screen( $current_screen ) {
    $this->current_screen = $current_screen;
  }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ new wpse(), 'load' ] );
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Help Nathan, But For The function get_current_screen() , i tried to use it directly in the if statement, but i fall in error [ call to undefined function ] . Could you give me a hint how to use it directly inside The Class .

Comment: What hook are you trying to use `get_current_screen()` on? I don't think it's available until `admin_init`. So if you try to use it in your class constructor, it won't be defined yet.

Comment: Simply i'm Creating a plugin settings Option , But The options Are created with tabed navigation and i wanted one of them to be the default to be shown one the user enter to the admin options page , so i wanted to check if the user is on the parent_base page then add_settings_section

Comment: please can you explain to me the thing you explained above about the class loading and the variable , i didn't understand well . thanks in advance .

Comment: You should ask a new question with your actual question (your comment starting with "Simply i'm Creating a plugin settings Option". This is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378).

Comment: Yeah Actually is Plugin But The only Problem i Have is that i wanna just check The user if it is on some specifi Screen in if statement .

Comment: This is The New question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300254/check-for-the-current-screen-oop Adn By the Way i learned a Lot from The XY Problems You told Me .

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to call `global` in `__construct()`. `global` only makes the variable available in the [current scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), which is just the `__construct()` method.

To make it available in other methods you need to call it in each method individually:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'method') );
    }

    public function method() {
        global $global_variable;

         if ( $global_variable ) {
             // Do Something ...
         }
    }
}
```

The other option is to assign the global variable as a class property, then refer to it in each method with `$this->`:

```
class MyClass {
    public $property;

    public function __construct() {
        global $global_variable;

        $this->property = $global_variable;

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'method') );
    }

    public function method() {
         if ( $this->property ) {
             // Do Something ...
         }
    }
}
```

However, as noted by Nathan in his answer, you need to be wary of when your class is instantiated, as it's possible that the global variable will nit be available at that point.

In those cases you would need to use my first example so that the variable is only referenced in a function that is hooked into the lifecycle at a point where the variable has been created.

Comment: The principle here is generally correct for using global variables in classes, but in your *specific* example with `$current_screen`, Nathan's approach is better.

Comment: Thanks Man For Your Help, But When i use it like you show me in the if statement , i face an error tell me that I'm Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: See Nathan's answer. Your class is probably being loaded before `$current_screen` is set (and even when it's never set), so it's not available in the construct method.

Comment: I'll update my answer to be more a more generic answer for global variables in classes, as the specific current screen example is wrong.